# Scheduled Flow showing numbers in decisions that don't exist yet

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a scheduled flow that is meant to update a record with numbers from child records. It uses more than one field to aggregate so can't be done via a rollup. The flow works but when debugging it and works correctly when in use but I am getting odd information in the debug log with ghost values that don't exist yet. The flow loops through the child records and adds numbers from different fields depending on what is populated to a number variable in the flow.  At the end I have a decision that if the total amount in the number variable after all the numbers have been added is different from the aggregate field in the record then the aggregate field should be updated. The record being debugged starts out with a null value and the flow treats it as having a null value but the data it shows in the debug is weird.  It shows the same number which doesn't make any sense because the record I am using to debug doesn't have any data in the aggregate students field. The field is null.
Outcome executed: Aggregate_of_Students_is_Different
Outcome conditions
{!$Record.District_Account__r.Aggregated_Students_in_District__c} (1,130) Does not equal {!AggregateNumberofStudents} (1,130)
All conditions must be true (AND)

It executed the correct outcome there because in reality the two are different, one is null and the other has a value but what it is showing are the same values - one value is a nonexistent ghost value.
I tried adding a decision at the beginning of the flow before I even do the addition just to see what happens and it does the same thing there.  Before it's even done the addition it's already showing the number from the addition in the debug, however it still behaves as if it were showing a null value. Here you can see what I mean:
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: Has_Aggregate_of_Students
Outcome conditions
{!$Record.District_Account__r.Aggregated_Students_in_District__c} (1,130) Greater than 0
All conditions must be true (AND)

Default outcome executed.

From the data it is showing (1,130) then it should have gone with the decision where 1,130 is greater than 0 but in reality the field has a null value so it executed the default outcome like it is supposed to do.  I just can't understand how/why it is putting the value of what it adds together in the flow before it's even been told to add it together - 1,130 is the number it gets after the flow has gone through the loops and added all the numbers together.  Or why it's putting it as a the value of the field that I have not yet told it to update with the value.  But it's not really putting it there because it still makes decisions as if it's not there....it's like this ghost value that exists but doesn't exist.

[image: Section 1 of Flow]

[image: Section 2 of Flow]

Comment: It seems you are trying to solve different issues at once.

1) Flow executing a wrong path based on comparison of two identical values
2) Record containing null value displays as 1,130
3) ...?

I suggest you create multiple questions, otherwise we can't help you. It's too confusing.

Comment: It's not 2 different issues - it's one.  The flow is executing the correct path based on the true values (null) but is showing values that aren't there yet.

Comment: Are there any other automations running before the Flow?

Comment: No, its a scheduled flow so runs on it's own in the middle of the night on an object with no other automations.